# Not able to set "Session" in ASP MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC. I want to use "Session" to store user input but I get the error:

> "The name 'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session' does not exist in
>   the current context."

The following code in my StudentController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebAppMVC.Models;

namespace WebAppMVC.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        string name = "New Name";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionString"] = name;
    }
}
```

I tried with `Current.Session` and also only `Session` What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session variable will give you the error "The name 'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session' does not exist in the current context." if you use the session variable outside ActionResult method. A session is used in web page class that has access to the Page.Session property, or any class that has access to the HttpContext.Current property.

So your code should be like :

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         string name = "New Name";
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionString"] = name;
    }
}
```

This way you can use and access session.
Instead you can write:

```
string name = "New Name";
Session["sessionString"] = name;
```

And to access the session variable using :

```
var session = Session["sessionString"].ToString();
```

Comment: This helps for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionString"] = name;
```

to

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("sessionString", name);
```

or

```
HttpContext.Session["sessionString"] = name;
```

Because in `Controller` class has property `HttpContext`

Comment: please run nuget for asp.net mvc dll by Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Comment: @Hien Nguyen Things doesn't work like this, this needs to be in proper section to use.